# How to parse and remove duplicates from aggregated text field

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have column with values like

```
select chipset_name from chipset

    chipset_name
    "Chip A,Chip B"
    "Chip A"
    "Chip F"
    "DSOG K"
    "FROW 01 33"
    "Chip F,DSOG K"
    ...
```

I want to aggregate it to one row without duplicate, but if I use string_agg(distinct..) I have duplicates

```
select string_agg(distinct chipset_labels,',')from chipset
----------
Chip A,Chip B,**Chip A**,Chip F,DSOG K,FROW 01 33,Chip F,**DSOG K**
```

How to parse and remove duplicates?

Thanks

Comment: Don't store multiple values in a single field.  Although Postgres does have functions to handle this, it is so much easier to use a proper relational structure.

Comment: I know it's incorrect, but I can't change it, DB is not on my DEV side(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `string_to_array(chipset_name, ',')` will transpose the names to arrays. Then `unnest` them and select only distinct values.

```
select distinct token
from 
    chipset, 
    unnest(string_to_array(chipset_name, ',')) token

   token    
------------
 Chip A
 Chip B
 Chip F
 DSOG K
 FROW 01 33
(5 rows)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

[`regexp_split_to_table`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) does not require unnesting:

```
select string_agg(distinct cl, ',')
from 
    chipset, 
    regexp_split_to_table(chipset_labels, ',') cl(cl)
;
               string_agg               
----------------------------------------
 Chip A,Chip B,Chip F,DSOG K,FROW 01 33
```